# create php web service and access to the internet

Tags: web-hosting

I have recently installed PHP, MySQL Server, and Apache web server. I played around with some PHP scripts locally on the PC to insert some entries to MySQL Database.

Noob question so please be patient with me:

How do I get my web service out to the internet, by self hosting? Say I already have a domain for example mydomain.com How do I make it so that when someone not within my network can access mydomain.com/something and can send some data so my server gets it and do anything with that data?

Comment: I see you edited your question to be more specific. While this is possible I'd like to advise against it. There are [numerous reasons](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+not+to+host+your+own+website) why not to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Webhosting

You have to have some form of webhosting. You pay for [hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_service) and you can upload your PHP files to their servers. They will usually also have database servers you can use.

Your domain name has to point to those servers via [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) so the internet can reach your application. I'd suggest you [search the internet](https://www.google.nl/?q=web+hosting) for popular hosts that provide the tools your need for this.

## Self hosting

Another possibility is to open your network up to the world, but this is not recommended unless you have network administration experience due the security trouble that comes with it.

In short: forward a port through your router to the machine running your application. The website [portforward.com](http://portfoward.com/) has instructions on how to do this but keep in mind that misconfiguration could lead to vulnerabilities in your network.

Answer (score -1):

In order to make you site public
 1. you need host
 2. you need domain

there are bunch of hosting sites you should get one first.

Comment: `you need domain`. Not necessarily. You can also make it accessible via the IP-address.

Answer (score -1):

This link explains very well about self hosting

https://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/hostmyown.html